# SQL statement optimization about query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT         
    oo.order_no,
    oo.line_type as order_label,
    oo.order_status,
    oo.order_type,
    oo.use_time,
    oo.company_no,
    oo.dispatch_type as dispatchType,
    oo.is_cp_driver as cpDriver,
    oo.service_type as serviceType,
    oo.real_service_type as realServiceType,
    0 as activity,
    0 as group_type     
    FROM os_order oo
    LEFT JOIN os_bill_info_before_update obibu ON oo.order_no = obibu.order_no
    WHERE oo.driver_no = 15163318 AND obibu.update_type = 3
      AND oo.use_time >= '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
      AND oo.use_time <= '2020-06-30 23:59:59.999'
    ORDER BY oo.use_time DESC
    LIMIT 0,22
```

[explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxH4M.png)
[explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw46D.png)

This is a order query. The query plan has been posted. Do you have any good suggestions

How to optimize the use filesort in extra
[show create table indexs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HE4H.png)

Comment: As well as the EXPLAIN, questions about query optimisation always require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables.

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: All of that said, composite indexes on some combination of `(os_order,order_no,driver_no,use_time)` for the first table, and
`(order_no,update_type)` for the second, would seem sensible. The perumtations are sufficiently small.

Comment: ...and I might be tempted to use  `AND oo.use_time < '2020-07-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: So,What can I optimize

Comment: You can drop all existing indexes. And recreate composite indexes on the columns indicated. The order of column selection matters, but I'm not sufficiently expert to say how, so I just test the different combinations to see what works best. There are 24 permutations to try, but I suspect you can rule out half of them pretty quickly.